# Valgrind on ARMv5

Tags: c++, c, arm, valgrind

I'm trying to debug a program on a embedded device. The problem is that it uses ARMv5 and valgrind doesn't support that platform (there are some patches over there but I was not able to make it work).

I tried some tools like gdb or memwatch, but it isn't enough to find the leaks.

Anyone could suggest a solution? I thought of maybe some kind of remote debugging or so.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Meanwhile, If you have a suspicious code segment which may cause memory leak you can post a another question,you may get additional help.

Comment: Is it running Linux? So it's a "large" embedded system, with a full (GNU?) libc and so on?

Comment: Hi. Yes, it's running a full linux. The problem is that I have some closed third party libs I suspect but need to use.

Comment: There are various 'libc' substitutes ([dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/), etc) which will replace 'malloc', 'free', 'strcpy', etc.  In some cases the instrumentation will work with binaries.  In others, it must be compiled with a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valgrind is a very powerful tool and it's pretty sad that it does not work on ARMv5 because it makes debugging memory leaks and invalid memory accesses more difficult on this platform.

I see several less powerful options. You can try to enable some additional checks within the C library by setting the [MALLOC_CHECK_](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html) environment variable. If your compiler is GCC 4.8 or higher you can try [AddressSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (I never used it on ARMv5 though).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about AddressSanitizer or MALLOC_CHECK, just updated GCC and trying it